# How could Red5 be integrated into an existing Spring Web application?

Tags: security, spring, integration, red5

I've made this question couple of days ago ([What is the best approach to develop a video chat web application in Java? Flex or JMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723049/what-is-the-best-approach-to-develop-a-video-chat-web-application-in-java-flex-o)) thanks to the answers given there we've decided to implement it with Flex + Red5, so the question now is, how can we implement Red5 into the existing Spring Web application? We can take advantages as much as we can of the Spring Security configuration that is currently in the Spring application and be able to call all the bussiness logic in there. So we are wondering if Red5 has to be deployed in a separate server or if we can somehow deploy it under the same Spring application as a separate servlet thus being able to use the same Spring Security configuration to secure the Red5 server? We know that Red5 configuration is based on Spring and for that reason we suppose that we can deploy it as another servlet together with Spring... is it possible? or we have to deploy Red5 in another server and configure another Spring security instance inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of questions :)

Basically, you just keep writing your server side logic as you are used to, with all the application context xmls you need, but keep in mind, that your main entry point (at least from amf) will be inside your Application extension class (any extra contexts should be loaded from there).

About deploying your application:

- You can have Red5 as a separate
  server -modified Tomcat- (in my opinion is the best),
  or
- You can deploy it under existing
  servers.

If you go with the first option, you'll be able to set up everything you need in a manner you always do, and you can also use it as a servlet container without any problems.

You might find the following links useful:

- [Getting Started With Red5 Server](http://red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_With_Red5_Server)
- [Begin Red5 Development](http://jwamicha.wordpress.com/2006/12/14/red-5-beginners-guide/)
- [Create new Java Red5
  Applications](http://jwamicha.wordpress.com/2007/01/29/create-a-new-java-red5-application/)
- [Spring Configs and Red5](http://gregoire.org/2009/01/18/spring-configs-and-red5-applications/)
- [Red5 and Hibernate (covering
  Spring)](http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/Tutorials/Red5AndHibernate)
- [Red5 and Acegi Security](http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/Tutorials/Red5AndAcegiSecurity)

Comment: Hi @rekaszeru, thank you so very much for your answer :) ... Ok now my doubt is, if we deploy it in a separate server, how we can use the existing Spring Security configuration? is there a way to make the Red5 server authenticate through the same Spring Security that we have in the Spring web application? (given that Red5 will be in a different server).

Comment: Remember that we already have an existing Spring Web app and we need to add a new functionality that supports video and chat, that's why we would want to put Red5 in the same server as the Spring App, to allow the Red5 code to access the same bussiness logic classes than the web app and to allow Spring Security to secure the Red5 app as well :)... is it possible? Or we have to deploy Red5 in a separate server? maybe from a performance point of view is better to have them in different servers but how can we make Red5 use the bussiness logic and security from the web app?

Comment: I see. My solution would be to change the server of the existing application: deploy it under a red5 server with all its configurations as is, and extend its functionality taking advantage of streaming, etc.

Comment: Ok @rekaszeru i will try your solution and see how it goes... Thank you very much for taking the time for answering my question :)

Comment: no problem, i hope you will get it to work as you'd like to! among the links, and on the red5's site you can find solutions for how to deploy existing web applications under red5.